# Creating iPad screenshots required for Apple Store submission

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I don't have a 12.9" iPad Pro, but the store requires iPad images with the dimensions of 2048x2732.  Is it possible to create an accurate screenshot image in that size without the use of the physical iPad?

Comment: do you have a Mac Computer with iCloud?

Comment: Yes, a MacBook pro.  Can you create them with that somehow in the correct dimensions?

Comment: You can upload the file to your laptop and open it in Preview.  You can then change the size in Preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the app in the Simulator that comes with Xcode. Set it up as a 12.9" iPad Pro and grab screenshots using the built-in tool.